# Lagrangian Multipliers exercise

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, manifolds

Let $M = \{(x, y, z) \in {\rm I\!R}^3 : F(x,y,z) = 0\}$ and let $F(x,y,z) = (3x^2z + y^2 + z^3-1, \, x + z-1)$ .

Does the function $f(x, y, z) = x$ have any extrema in $M$?

We are asked in advance to prove that $M$ is a manifold. Thus I believe that we have to use the method of Lagrangian Multipliers to solve the exercise, but I can't seem to solve the system.

This is what I have so far:

> \begin{cases} (1,0,0) = \lambda_{1}(6xz,\,2y,\,3z^2) + \lambda_{2}(1,\,0,1)
> \\3x^2z + y^2 + z^3=1  \\ x+z = 1 \end{cases}

Comment: what kind of system do you have found?

Comment: It's not linear. I'll add it to the question.